Filter overlapping time periods using sqlalchemy for mySQL
I'm having soo much trouble trying to make this work.
Im developing an API where there are activities (called 'Session' in the model), those have two time related attributes, DATE (the initial datetime of the activity itself) and DURATION (the duration of the activity itself).
When a new activity is created, I want to check if the staff that will be working on the new activity will overlap with another activity.
I'm using python (fastAPI) as a BE framework and using a mySQL database. For the moment I've made the following approaches:
def get_overlapping_staffSession(db: Session, session: schemas.SessionCreate) -> list[models.StaffSession]:
    staff_ids = []

    new_session_start = session.date
    new_session_end = (session.date + timedelta(hours=session.duration))

    for staff in session.staff:
        staff_ids.append(staff.id)

    overlapping_sessions = (
        db.query(models.StaffSession)
        .join(models.Session, models.StaffSession.id_session == models.Session.id)
        .filter(
            and_(
                models.StaffSession.id_staff.in_(staff_ids),
                models.Session.date <= new_session_end,
                models.Session.date + (models.Session.duration * timedelta(hours=1)) >= new_session_start
            )
        )
    ).all()

    return overlapping_sessions

This should return an array with the models StaffSession that are within the new time range and have staff that will work in the new activity.
The value session.date is of type datetime and the column date in the model Session is of type datetime.
I've seen different examples online that have no trouble using this.
To make sure that it works I tried implementing the same query in mySQL, the following uses the same values (id and time range) as the ones used to test the code above.
SELECT 
    staffsession.*
FROM 
    staffsession
JOIN 
    session ON staffsession.id_session = session.id
WHERE 
    staffsession.id_staff IN (12)
    AND session.date <= '2024-04-15T16:30:00+01:00'
    AND session.date + INTERVAL session.duration SECOND >= '2024-04-15T13:30:00+01:00';

While doing this query it works perfectly in mySQL, in the API it returns all StaffSession that contain the ids in staff_ids, but not filtering by date.
Any help will be more than welcome and thank you for your time.

If your SQL query is working as intended but SQLAlchemy is not that can only mean one thing: the SQL Query send by SQLAlchemy differs, if you set the engine parameter echo=True Python will log the send statement which will likely help solve your issue. I'd also advice you to very aware of the SQLAlchemy version you're using, many of the historical answers are for <2.0 - as you're using query()  & filter() as opposed to select() & where() I'm guessing you're looking at outdated answers - been there myself.

There Session.duration*timedelta(hours=1)  and INTERVAL session.duration SECOND. Is this true?

According to the SQLAlchemy docs for the INTERVAL type:

A type for datetime.timedelta() objects.
The Interval type deals with datetime.timedelta objects. In PostgreSQL and Oracle, the native INTERVAL type is used; for others, the value is stored as a date which is relative to the “epoch” (Jan. 1, 1970).
Note that the Interval type does not currently provide date arithmetic operations on platforms which do not support interval types natively. Such operations usually require transformation of both sides of the expression (such as, conversion of both sides into integer epoch values first) which currently is a manual procedure (such as via expression.func).

So datetime arithmetic using intervals is not directly supported on MySQL. We can verify this by executing the interval arithmetic from the query in the question on some sample dates:
import sqlalchemy as sa

engine = sa.create_engine(...)
sessions = sa.Table(...)

# (create the table, insert some dates...)

QUERY = """
SELECT 
    date + INTERVAL duration SECOND
FROM 
    sessions
ORDER BY id
"""

with engine.connect() as conn:
    rows = conn.execute(sa.text(QUERY))
    for row in rows:
        print(row)

outputs
(datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 15, 17, 30),)
(datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 15, 17, 0),)
(datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 15, 13, 0),)

but the SQLAlchemy query
with engine.connect() as conn:
    q = sa.select(
        sessions.c.date + (sessions.c.duration * dt.timedelta(hours=1))
    ).order_by(sessions.c.id)
    rows = conn.execute(q)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)

outputs
(20240422255000.0,)
(20240422252000.0,)
(20240422212000.0,)

There are at least two ways to work around this. We can convert all the elements to UNIX timestamps and back, or we can use sqlalchemy.text to insert the required SQL.
with engine.connect() as conn:
    q = sa.select(
        sa.func.from_unixtime(
            sa.func.unix_timestamp(sessions.c.date) + (sessions.c.duration)
        ),
        sessions.c.date + sa.text('INTERVAL sessions.duration SECOND')
        
    ).order_by(sessions.c.id)
    rows = conn.execute(q)
    for row in rows:
        print(row)

giving us
(datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 15, 17, 30), datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 15, 17, 30))
(datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 15, 17, 0), datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 15, 17, 0))
(datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 15, 13, 0), datetime.datetime(2024, 4, 15, 13, 0))

The above example use SQLAlchemy's core syntax.  The equivalent ORM syntax would be
overlapping_sessions = (
    db.query(models.StaffSession)
    .join(models.Session, models.StaffSession.id_session == models.Session.id)
    .filter(
        and_(
            models.StaffSession.id_staff.in_(staff_ids),
            models.Session.date <= new_session_end,
            sa.func.from_unixtime(sa.func.unix_timestamp(models.Sessions.date) + (model.Session.duration)) >= new_session_start
        )
    )
).all()


Applying the workaround of converting the timestamp to unix worked seamless. Thanks for your extense answer!
